# Removing rusted screws from a gate-post attached to a wall

Tags: screws, gate-post, rust

I am changing my old rusted garden gate with a new one. However, because of a couple of rusted screws, I could not remove the gate-post attached to the walls on either end of the old gate.

I tried applying WD-40 lubricant to loosen the screw so I could unscrew them using a screwdriver, but I hadn’t had very much luck with that. Later I tried lightly striking the gate-post with a hammer, hoping to loosen it from the wall, but that didn’t work either.

Is there another approach I can take to remove a rusted screw from the wall?

Comment: FYI.  WD40 is not a lubricant, it is a penetrate and this would be a correct application for it IF all the parts are metal. PB blaster is a much better penetrate. Have you tried-grips on  screw heads ?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply - no, I haven't heard of it until now. I will give @JACK's suggestion ago before I make a trip to DIY store for a screw extractor or locking pliers.

Comment: What kind of screws, what kind of wall ? What kind of post ?  A photo May be enlightening.

Comment: It's a standard flat head screw securing the iron gate-post to a brick wall. (I will upload a photo as soon as possible)

Comment: How much space is there to each side and behind?

Comment: There is about 3-4mm space between iron gate-post and the wall, enough to put a hammer claw in it.

Comment: It sounds like there be enough room to get long reciprocating saw blade in between the post and the wall and cut the screws.

Answer (score 4):

What has worked for me in the past is grinding the heads off with a Dremel tool and cutoff wheel or any other type of portable grinder.A hack saw might do the trick too. Then pry the posts away from the wall and then grasp the remaining portion of the screw with a pair of vise grips and turning it counterclockwise. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, @JACK - will try that out

Answer (score 0):

A **Manual Impact Driver** is designed to do exactly what you need...if you haven't already cut the head of the screws off.

They aren't expensive.

[image]